# Selecting users who can read document for each row entered in form

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I made an application where I upload files that are visible to all users. I used Joomla Fabrik for that.

Now for each file/row that I uploaded I want to select the users who can see that file. And those users must be able to confirm by clicking some checkbox that they read file so that I can check that everyone read the file.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: So basically you want to implement a file permission system for your application? The part with selecting users who can see certain file is easy; it can be similar with the implementation of permissions for files and folders in OS. The management of who read depends to much on the user. What if he read and doesn't click because he forgots? What if he doesn't read but clicks? You can add a flag for reading the document in the permissions mapping.

Comment: @Coral Doe : Thank u very much.that is exactly the problem. but Client requirement is like this. How can i add a flag in permissions mapping ?as file that i am uploading is through fabrik element file upload. Do i need to make changes in core files ? and how will i get list of all users available for all files independently,

Comment: Does Fabrick store the files in a database?

Comment: @Coral Doe : yes file link is stored in database . when we click on link from fabrik list file gets opened

Comment: I am feeling lost for the moment.

Comment: @CoralDoe : I started one more thread. Nobody answered yet.please help me. it is with heading :link of module inside other module joomla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is a rather basic one, as a table of permissions.

Create a new table with columns (mine are merely an example)
FILE_IDENTIFICATOR USER_IDENTIFICATOR CAN_READ HAVE_READ

This table will contain the file-user association. If a user can read a file, simply set CAN_READ to true. If the user has checked that he has read, set HAVE_READ to true (by default HAVE_READ should be false).
The FILE_IDENTIFICATOR and USER_IDENTIFICATOR depend on your system implementation.
Rows can be added to this table each time you give access to an user for a file or you can add all the user-file associations (thought this could lead to a large table).

It is a simple method, just using table accessing operation, but you have to model de workflows that check the CAN_READ and HAVE_READ flags and add the file-user associations.

Comment: Thnks ..But how , i already made one modeule that fetch list of all users and shows a checkbox infront of everyuser . But i am not able to save/insert that into table, and specially how to associate this list individually/seperately for all files that are uploaded through fabrik. What element must be added in fabrik form that will take me to the module that shows userlist and checkboxes ?  In short how do we insert data in forms, and how will i associate that selection with each file ,lastly how will i create an element in fabrik that will take me to that selection part

Comment: You can make a module that fetches all the files and then for every file you show a button for a workflow that adds a user as a reader for that file. So you can individually add for each file and associate a selection with each file. The selection part can be a separate form/window. To insert data into a table, you can look at the example here http://fabrikar.com/wiki/index.php/Common_Joomla_PHP_tasks `Insert some data into a a database`. But if you have issues so deep into implementation, you will need to ask specific separate questions or study more about joomla, php and fabrik.